# Laravel - selecting a record with relationship many-to-many, append extra field for each relation

Tags: laravel

I need to add fields for each relationship eg $record->lists(), and for each list I need to add extra field - I was wondering if there's a way to do it by using some closure magic, or if I should foreach the array.

**edit**

Current solution

```
    $relatedLists = $item->lists()->with([
        'user' => function($query){ $query->select('nickname', 'id');}
    ])->get();

    foreach( $relatedLists as $index => $list) {
        $rating = $item->ratingsByUserId($list->user_id)->first();
        $relatedLists[$index]->rated_by_user = empty($rating) ? 0 : $rating->rated;
    }
```

Comment: when you say "field" do you mean add attributes on the fly?

Comment: @sam12 yeah, I was wondering if there was some elegant solution, don't really like current one - added to the question

Answer (score 0):

For many-to-many relationships you can use `attach()` method and pass an array of additional values that are defined on your pivot table

```sql
$record->lists()->attach([
    1 => ['extrafield' => 'extravalue1'],
    2 => ['extrafield' => 'extravalue2'],
]);
```

The above code attaches lists with ids `1` and `2` to the record and sets extrafield values to `'extravalue1'` and `'extravalue2'` accordingly.

Further reading [Many To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

You can append extra attribute in model( which is not in table as field) by using `appends` variable. Also you can create mutrators for those appended attributes.

Example

```
protected $appends = ['is_admin'];

public function getIsAdminAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['admin'] == 'yes';
}
```